# R: Find non-corresponding columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match, extract

think of this small example data frame (the real data frame is huge):

`df <- data.frame(ID=c("C_40", "C_40", "A_301", "A_301", "T_014", "C_4301", "C_4301", "A_345"), genID=c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3","3","4", "4"))`

I am struggling with the following problem:
You see that there are always 2 IDs corresponding to a genID.

The "right" cases are where the ID and genID column match, so the first 2 (C_48 is 1, A_301 is 2). 
The others are "false", I need to detect them (in this example, genID 3 has non-matching IDs = T_014 and C_4301; the same holds for genID4.

Do you know a way how I can extract these non-matching cases? Eg. to a data frame that shows only the non-matches, here for example looking like this:

```
 ID     genID
T_014   3
C_4301  3
C_4301  4
A_345   4
```

So I need the cases where the same genID has differing IDs...
Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

We group by 'genID' and `filter` based on the condition that the number of distinct 'ID's are equal to 2

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(genID) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(ID) == 2)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   genID [2]
#  ID     genID
#  <fct>  <fct>
#1 T_014  3    
#2 C_4301 3    
#3 C_4301 4    
#4 A_345  4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a very effective solution to use with a large dataset, I would suggest to use the `data.table` package. This code snippet should answer to what you need.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
unique(df)[, .(ID, count=.N), genID][count>1][, count:=NULL][]

##     genID     ID
##  1:     3  T_014
##  2:     3 C_4301
##  3:     4 C_4301
##  4:     4  A_345
```